# c# how to convert a datetime to byte array of 4 bytes

Tags: c#

I tried converting it to byte array, but a minimum byte array of 5 is created.
But I have only 4 bytes only for this date time to stored as byte in my array of byte.

code is like this:

```
byte[] b = new byte[] {10,12,12,12};
DATETIME t=datetime.now();
array.copy(BitConverter.GetBytes(t.ticks),1,b,4);
```

but `getbytes(t.ticks)` returns array of 8 bytes. I somehow want it to convert to 4 bytes only.

Comment: Do you need to store just the date, or the entire date + time?

Comment: 4 bytes simply isn't enough. So you need to either sacrifice range or accuracy. `DateTime` supports dates from the year 1 to 9999 in 100ns steps. This requires 8 bytes.

Comment: ...or increase the size of whatever you are storing it in.

Comment: complete datetime in 4 bytes

Comment: @user3229083 You can't fit a `DateTime` into 4 bytes without sacrificing *something*. It was designed to fit 8 bytes, not 4. That's a mathematical limitation you can't get around. It's like trying 4 different values in a single bit. For example if you reduce accuracy to 1 sec you get a range of around 130 years, which is the trade-off chosen by unix time stamps.

Comment: i only need date 2/1/2014 and time 11:44 in these 4 bytes, dont need seconds. cant i get it in 4 bytes.

Comment: What is the earliest time you need to store? November 1582? January 2014?

Comment: You could use an unsigned 32 bit unix time stamp which can represent dates from 1970 to 2100. Or you could divide the unix timestamp by 60 since you only need minutes which should give you a few thousand years of range.

Answer (score 9):

You can use 32 bit unix time. But be careful with year 2038 problem. You can find sample solution below. Which stores date time in 4 bytes.

```
        byte[] b = new byte[] { 10, 12, 12, 12 };
        DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
        var epoch = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
        var csMinDate = DateTime.MinValue;
        TimeSpan tsEpoch = now - epoch;
        int passedSecods = (int)tsEpoch.TotalSeconds;
        byte[] copyBytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(passedSecods);
        Array.Copy(copyBytes, 0, b, 0, 4);
        DateTime tCompare = epoch.AddSeconds(BitConverter.ToInt32(b, 0));
```

Comment: how do you reverse it back? from 4 byte array to DataTime

Comment: as follows (it is in the solution);  
        DateTime tCompare = epoch.AddSeconds(BitConverter.ToInt32(b, 0));

Answer (score 1):

Convert current time to 64 bit unix time then manually convert the 64 bit time to 32 bit time (be ready to face the Year 2038 problem.).

See SO discussion for ideas to do this:

- [portable way to deal with 64/32 bit time_t](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2467418/portable-way-to-deal-with-64-32-bit-time-t)
- [How do I convert from a 32-bit int representing time in usec to a 32-bit int representing time as a binary fraction in secs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/550686/how-do-i-convert-from-a-32-bit-int-representing-time-in-usec-to-a-32-bit-int-rep)

Other References:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem
- [How do you convert epoch time in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2883576/how-do-you-convert-epoch-time-in-c)

Answer (score -1):

try with this code:

```
byte[] b = new byte[] { 10, 12, 12, 12 };
DateTime t = DateTime.Now;
Array.Copy(BitConverter.GetBytes(t.Ticks), 0, b, 0, 4);
```

Comment: dat just store the first 4 byte from 8 byte recieved from GetByte(t.ticks)... the other 4 bytes are lost.